# How do I setup the esc key to exit Godot Application?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a question about something I'm getting stuck on with a new 2D project. I added a sprite background and it shows no problem when I run the test. I setup the esc key as "key_exit" in the Input Map. Then I created a node2D as the root and added the following script to it:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
   if Input.is_action_pressed("key_exit"):
      get_tree().quit()
```

It doesn't work. I'm trying to create a simple loop that listens for esc key presses and quits when I press the escape key. If I add get_tree().quit() without the if condition, it quits as soon as it starts. How do I get it to "listen" for my if condition? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. I was able to get it working with the following:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
   if Input.is_action_pressed("key_exit"):
      get_tree().quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to Godot's Q&A](https://ask.godotengine.org/14196/how-do-i-setup-the-esc-key-to-exit-the-program), with Godot 3.1+, the good way to do it is:

```py
func _input(event):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        get_tree().quit()
```

It works for me with Godot 4.1.

According to [Sending your own quit notification](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/handling_quit_requests.html) you also need

```py
get_tree().root.propagate_notification(NOTIFICATION_WM_CLOSE_REQUEST)
```

before it, but I could not check it, in my trivial sample code.